# XML Request into Js Array only reaching 1000 entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending an XMLHttpRequest to NASA's API for their entire star database, which is over 100k. I'm then feeding the JSON data into a JavaScript array, but strangely only 1000 entries are coming through. Here's my code:

```
// SET UP XML DATABASE REQUEST
var databaseUrl = 'https://data.nasa.gov/resource/5bv2-dyn2';
var databaseXml = new XMLHttpRequest();
databaseXml.open('GET', databaseUrl, true);

// SEND XML DATABASE REQUEST
databaseXml.send(null);

// WHEN REQUEST IS READY, PUT DATABASE INTO ARRAY
databaseXml.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (databaseXml.readyState==4 && databaseXml.status==200) {
        window.databaseParse = JSON.parse(databaseXml.responseText);
        window.starDatabase = [];
        window.databaseParse.forEach(function(el) {
            window.starDatabase.push(el.label)
        })
        console.log(starDatabase.length);
    }
}
```

I'm printing the database length to the console, and it's definitely 1000. What am I doing wrong here? Surely it's something simple.

Comment: Perhaps their API limits the amount of response data fetched to protect against DDoS?

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong here, the `NASA API` itself is sending 1000 records only.. you can see it yourself in developers tool's `network` tab

Comment: @vinayakj You're right, it appears this has to do with Socrata's limit of 1000 requests per hour. I would have thought that one xml request for the entire database would be interpreted as one request, and the response would be one big array...

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing anything wrong here, the NASA API itself is sending 1000 records only.. you can see it yourself in developers tool's network tab